# Why does Optional Chaining lead to "Property 'xxxxx' does not exist on type 'never'" pre-transpilation error?

Tags: typescript

As stated in [TypeScript 3.7 reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html) on optional chaining, we can secure access to properties or methods to possibly `null` or `undefined` instances with the `?.` notation.

Under TypeScript 4.9.4, `tsconfig.json` (`target: "ES2020"` & `module: "commonjs"`), Visual Studio Code, different situations lead to pre-transpilation errors: "Property 'xxxxx' does not exist on type 'never'".

```
let a
let a: string | null = null
let a: string | undefined = undefined

console.log( a?.toString() )   // << "Property 'toString' does not exist on type 'never'"
```

The only way I had identified it worked is in case of intermediary of function or lambda (arrow function) interfaces:

```
let lambda = (value: string | null) => {
    console.log(value?.toString())       // << no complaining
}

let a = null
lambda(a)                                // << no complaining

a = "Hello World!"
lambda(a)
```

In that case, the pre-transpiler doesn't complain.

What is the reason why it doesn't work as the documentation says it must?

Comment: The compiler knows you assigned undefined and have had no chance to assign anything else, hence infers `never`. In an example where it can _actually_ be `string | undefined`, as in your second examples, it works as expected: https://tsplay.dev/Wk3L0W

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**:

While the pre-compiler can define the instance is `null` or `undefined` it will complain that expectation of test (?.) is always irrelevant.
It's simply because the code outcomes to a static situation (invariable) where the instance is `null` or `undefined`.

**Detailed answer**:

When you write an expression with [optional chaining (`?.`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)...

```
let a: string | undefined = undefined;
a?.toString();
```

...you actually do:

```
a && a.toString();
```

which is logically equal to:

```
if (a) {
  a.toString();
}
```

We know that `if` is one way to [*narrow*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) a variable.

> TypeScript follows possible paths of execution that our programs can take to analyze the most specific possible type of a value at a given position. [...] and the process of refining types to more specific types than declared is called *narrowing*.

That is exactly what's going on here. TypeScript understands that `a` is actually `undefined` in the first place.

```
let a: string | undefined = undefined;
  a;
//^? let a: undefined
```

The optional chaining/`if`-statement acts as another type guard. It ensures that `a` is not `null` or `undefined`. At this point we have considered all possibilities. `a` is neither a `string` nor `undefined`. For such situations the [`never`-type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never) comes into play.

> Variables also acquire the type never when narrowed by any type guards that can never be true.

---

The reason it works inside a function block is because there's no way to know what's coming in as an argument at compile time. So this time the value really is `string | undefined`.

```
let lambda = (value: string | undefined) => {
  value?.toString();
  //^? (parameter) value: string | undefined
};
```